# can one google account be used to upload different applications on android market?

Tags: upload, google-play

can I use the same google account to upload many different applications on android market,
or I have to create different ones for different applications?
thank you for answering.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can. A developer can make more than only one application ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can have as many applications as you desire published through one Google Play (no longer Market) developer account.